# Avoid external calls while loading page in iframe

Tags: html, iframe

I have an iframe which is loading some pages dynamically. These pages are just html pages but they can have reference to external resources such as java script files or images. So when I am loading page inside iframe, it is trying to download these images from internet and in most of cases, I am getting HTTP 404 code. Is there a way wherein I can load only HTML content and avoid making any HTTP requests for downloading external content?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no good solution to your problem. If the html page in the iframe is at the same domain as the parent page's, you can use some javascript code to block the external resources. If else, the parent page will not be permitted to control the iframe.